# how to analysis Spring Boot Memory leak

Tags: spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot project in my company.
After 20 to 30 days of deploying the project, there was an issue that gradually increased memory.
So I'm analyzing the dump using Eclipse's MAT, but it's not easy.
Would it be possible to get some help?

Use aws' SQS, S3, etc. in the project.

It is a project to receive data from SQS, store it in S3, and send the summary of the data to another server.

I'm sorry that I can't release the code due to security issues.
It's hard to correct the code and show it because I can't guess which code may have caused a memory leak.

save to S3

```
 public String saveOriginS3(OriginDataDTO data) {
    try {
        var placeType = PlaceType.ofPlaceId(data.identifier().hostMarketplaceId());
        var key = placeType.getKeyWithPostfix(data.itemId());
        var valueAsBytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(s3PropertiesStatic.AMZ_S3,
                                                                 key,
                                                                 new ByteArrayInputStream(valueAsBytes),
                                                                 getObjectMetadata(valueAsBytes));
        abcS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);

        URL url = abcS3.getUrl(s3PropertiesStatic.AMZ_S3,
                               key);
        return url.toString();
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.error("", e);
    }

    return "";
}
```

get data by S3

```
try {
        String presignedUrl = getPresignedUrl(amazonUrl, marketPlaceType);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(presignedUrl)) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(presignedUrl)
                                      .build(true)
                                      .toUri();

        var body = bucketTemplate.getForEntity(uri, byte[].class)
                                 .getBody();
        if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(body)) {
            
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        var datas = new String(body, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return objectMapper.readValue(datas, DataWrapperDTO.class)
                           .customerReviews();

    } catch (IOException | RestClientException e) {
        
    }

    return Collections.emptyList();
```

[leak suspects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKTgr.png)
[list objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSII0.png)